# Window running function except current row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a theoretical question, so I'm not interested in alternative solutions. Sorry.

Q: Is it possible to get the window running function values for all previous rows, except current?

For example:

```
with
  t(i,x,y) as (
    values
      (1,1,1),(2,1,3),(3,1,2),
      (4,2,4),(5,2,2),(6,2,8)
    )
select
  t.*,
  sum(y) over (partition by x order by i) - y as sum,
  max(y) over (partition by x order by i) as max,
  count(*) filter (where y > 2) over (partition by x order by i) as cnt
from
  t;
```

Actual result is

```
 i | x | y | sum | max | cnt 
---+---+---+-----+-----+-----
 1 | 1 | 1 |   0 |   1 |   0
 2 | 1 | 3 |   1 |   3 |   1
 3 | 1 | 2 |   4 |   3 |   1
 4 | 2 | 4 |   0 |   4 |   1
 5 | 2 | 2 |   4 |   4 |   1
 6 | 2 | 8 |   6 |   8 |   2
(6 rows)
```

I want to have `max` and `cnt` columns behavior like `sum` column, so, result should be:

```
 i | x | y | sum | max | cnt 
---+---+---+-----+-----+-----
 1 | 1 | 1 |   0 |     |   0
 2 | 1 | 3 |   1 |   1 |   0
 3 | 1 | 2 |   4 |   3 |   1
 4 | 2 | 4 |   0 |     |   0
 5 | 2 | 2 |   4 |   4 |   1
 6 | 2 | 8 |   6 |   4 |   1
(6 rows)
```

It can be achieved using simple subquery like

```
select t.*, lag(y,1) over (partition by x order by i) as yy from t
```

but is it possible using only window function syntax, without subqueries?

Comment: I'd try filter with `t.i <> i`

Comment: @Lashane It is equal to `t.i <> t.i` or just `i<>i`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can. This does the trick:

```
with
  t(i,x,y) as (
    values
      (1,1,1),(2,1,3),(3,1,2),
      (4,2,4),(5,2,2),(6,2,8)
    )
select
  t.*,
  sum(y) over w as sum,
  max(y) over w as max,
  count(*) filter (where y > 2) over w as cnt
from t
window w as (partition by x order by i
             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding);
```

The [`frame_clause`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) selects just those rows from the window frame that you are interested in.

Note that in the `sum` column you'll get `null` rather than `0` because of the frame clause: the first row in the frame has no row before it. You can `coalesce()` this away if needed.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27abb/5)